# Bootstrap Radio Button group not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I dont why but the radio button group is displaying the button/label and the radio button separate, different from the example on the bootstrap website

the code is just copy pasted from bootstrap (i also included the parent div)

```
<div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[running the HTML it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9TEs.png)

how can i make it so that it looks like the one on bootsrap example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ive edited the question, i hope it is more clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the input in to the label without separating label and input li below mentioned code

```
<div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
   <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">

     <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1</label>

   </div>
 </div>
```

The example image

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt solve my problem i want it to show like what in the bootstrap example is. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/

Comment: then try with CSS go to the link you mentioned and inspect that button in developer tools and see the CSS of button group and change according to your code   , in between i know the bootstrap CSS is predefined but don't know why it does not work try with CSS using important command

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, make sure you're using the latest version of bootstrap, that solved it for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the btn-group class to the wrapping div like so

```
<div class="col-5 d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Radio 1</label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Radio 2</label>
</div>
```